# blackberry webworks app getting timed out

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, blackberry, timeout, blackberry-webworks

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://myurl:port/projectpath.action",
        data: formInput,
        dataType: "TEXT",
        timeout:600000,
        async: true,
        success:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

            alert("error :" + textStatus);
            alert("incoming Text :" + jqXHR.responseText);
            alert("What ErrorThrown :" + errorThrown);
            $('#loader').hide();
            window.location.replace("paymentResult.html");
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

            alert("error " + textStatus);
            alert("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
            alert("What ErrorThrown" +errorThrown);
            $('#loader').hide();
            //alert(xhr.status+"  Server Unavailable! Please try again later");
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

I'm getting timed out although I am setting the ajax time out..and in the config file I have also mentioned the timeout... still it is getting timed out...

```
alert("What ErrorThrown" +errorThrown);
```

The alert message above shows and in my config file, my parameters passed are:

```
"rim:connection timeout="600000""
"id"TCP_WIFI"/id"
"id"MDS"/id"
"id"BIS-B"/id"
"id"TCP_CELLULAR"/id"
"id"WAP2"/id"
"id"WAP"/id"
"/rim:connection"
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your config.xml you should also be setting up an access element.

```
<access uri="*" subdomains="true" />
```

Can you confirm if you're doing this already?  If so, and it still gets no response, could you tell me what OS/device you're targeting? If it's running BlackBerry OS 7 or higher (or PlayBook/BB10) you can use Remote Web Inspector to watch real-time what's happening with your ajax request, and debug it that way.

More on [Remote Web Inspector...](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/getting_started_webinsp_microsite_1987477_11.html)

Comment: yes i am using the access uri parameter in my config.xml.but still the problem is on..there are several othar url calls in my project they are working fine...but only for this particular url it is giving a "Gateway Timeout" in alert("What Error" + errorThrown); . so can you plz tell me about that...

Comment: yes i am using the access uri parameter in my config.xml.but still the problem is on..there are several othar url calls in my project they are working fine...but only for this particular url it is giving a "Gateway Timeout" in alert("What Error" + errorThrown); . so can you plz tell me about that...i am using blackberry os 6..handset 9300

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing the same results when using WiFi only? Turn off the mobile network, connect to WiFi and see if you get the same result.